# JSLink html image path to a SiteCollection StyleLibrary in a SubSite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jslink

Currently I am trying to reference my SiteCollection  Style Library  image directory  in a  javascript file linked up to a DocumentLibrary Webpart  in a subsite.

The current directory I am attempting to do this is

```
 src="/Style Library/images/'
```

I believe this should have worked as I replicated the xlsx icon generation by using

```
src="/_layouts/15/images/icxlsx.png"
```

Well I just cut and pasted the html src to my Sitecollection webpath and I am able to get the image to show up so currently I am unaware of what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh ha  I found out the answer.

The path

```
src="/_layouts/15/images/icxlsx.png"
```

point to the   host web path  of

```
https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/images/icxlsx.png
```

If you wish to access a sitecollection Style Library then you will need to add that onto the url such as

```
/Sites/Style library/ ...
```

or what ever you have named your site collection.
Now the weird thing about this is that the tolken for JSLink you can only use

~controlTemplates 
~layouts 
~site 
~sitecollection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831(v=office.15).aspx

I believe then this means that if you wish to use the JSLink to a javascript file on your host site when you are on a different sitecollection  you will have to use the full https:// url path to your javascript file.

Kinda silly but hopefully one day they will give us a token that will allow a quick reference to the host web of your site.